# PhpStorm - Issue with Xdebug : Cannot find file '/project_path/Standard input code' locally on test file

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, atoum

I'm struggling to get Xdebug to work in a PHP test file on PhpStorm 2020.

I need to debug some tests class along with the Xdebug extension, but I always get this :

```
Cannot find file '/project_path/Standard input code' locally.
To fix it set server name by environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG and restart debug session.
```

I tried everything I found on the web to fix it, but nothing seems to work in my case.

I tried to set `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` as an environment variable and set to `localhost`, also add localhost server in the IDE but still nothing works. My colleagues didn't have to make any specific configuration to get Xdebug to work in their IDE.

The "normal" PHP files work, I have this issue only on test files.

Any idea ?

Comment: Xdebug sees this bogus file `Standard input code` and sends us the debug data for it. Since we have no idea where to map it to, we show you the error message. You can work the issue around by configuring `PHP | Servers` mappings manually and then unchecking `PHP | Debug | Break at first line when no mapping specified`

Comment: @EugeneMorozov you can post this as an answer so that I can close this question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Xdebug sees this bogus file `Standard input code` and sends us the debug data for it. Since we have no idea where to map it to, we show you the error message.
You can work the issue around by configuring `PHP | Servers` mappings manually and then unchecking `PHP | Debug | Break at first line when no mapping specified`.

Comment: This wasn't enough: I also had to uncheck `PHP | Debug | Xdebug | Force break at first line when no path mapping specified`, after which the issue really disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling into this, the underlying problem is that `PHPUnit` opens a child process for each test by creating some in-memory PHP code which is sent to the standard input of that process.

So, if you want to debug your tests, make sure you set `processIsolation` to "false" in your `phpunit.xml`. This way `PHPUnit` won't create child processes and xdebug is not stuck at this.

```xml
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
  processIsolation="false"
>
```